# Response::download error because of header in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Controller:

```
public function download(){

 $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'text/csv');
 return Response::download('download.csv', 'download.csv', $headers)->setContentDisposition('inline');

}
```

Filter:

```
 $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

Error:

```
 [2016-01-19 15:34:29] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\development\app\filters.php:60
  Stack trace:
  #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
  #1 {main} [] []
```

I don't know how to solve this kind of problem. I already tried [this](http://laravel.io/forum/03-17-2014-cannot-set-cache-control-in-laravel-4) but still not working.

Comment: Why did you tag both Laravel versions? I assume you are using Laravel 4 as you have specified the use of a Filter?

Comment: @MikeRockett yes sorry for that. Maybe there's someone who can help me in terms of headers in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/palanik/lumen-cors/issues/9

```
/**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = new Response("", 200);
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
        }

        // Added this to fix the image download problem
        // Only set Cors if its not een image
        if(strpos($response->headers->get('content-type'), 'image') === false) {
          $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);
        }

        return $response;
    }
```